# Floating point: is a / b - 1 > 0 if a > b

Tags: floating-point

Assuming IEEE 754 of any precision, is `a / b - 1.0 > 0.0` for all finite floats `a` and `b` where `a > b > 0`?  Is this compiler dependent?  How can this property be proven or disproven?  The short script below returns true.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.rand(1000000)
np.all((np.nextafter(arr, np.inf) / arr - 1) > 0.0)
```

Comment: @NarasimhaPrasannaHN: "...for all finite floats a and b where a > b".  So you don't have to worry about infinite floats :)

Comment: I just tried in browser console, the value of `a = 10.00000000000000000000001` and `b = 9.9999999999999999999999`, JavaScript however approximated it to 10.0 each, so answer was 0.0, thus False

Comment: So, yeah, under a finite precision the condition holds true

Comment: Well, trivially it's not true if `b == 0`, but I expect you meant to exclude that case.

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes, good catch.  updated question accordingly

Comment: @NarasimhaPrasannaHN The problem with your comment is that, although you typed those values for `a` and `b`, they were rounded into double precision floating point as 10.0, so `a == b` not `a > b`.  You just had a fancy way of inputing 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's true in the usual round-to-even.  Without loss of generality, suppose `1 <= a < 2`.  In round-to-even, if `b < 1`, then `a/b = sum(i=0..infty) (1-b)^i a > a + (1-b)a >= a + ulp(a)/2 a`, so `round-to-even(a/b) > a`.  So we can assume `1 <= b < a < 2`.  You can compute `a/b = 1 + (a-b)/b > 1 + (a-b)/2 >= 1 + ulp(a)/2`, `so round-to-even(a/b) > 1`.

Comment: That is usually called round-to-nearest or round-to-nearest-ties-to-even.

Answer (score 1):

This is an experimental supplement to the [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57378556/1798593). If the claim does fail, it will be when the ratio between two distinct floats is as close as possible to 1.0. That happens when their difference is as small as possible relative to their magnitude.

At each power of two, the absolute gap between consecutive pairs doubles. The interesting case is when `a` is a power of two and `b` is the next float down. That is the largest magnitude pair using the smaller gap size. In Java:

```
public strictfp class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double a = 1.0;
    double b = Math.nextDown(a);
    System.out.println(a/b-1);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
2.220446049250313E-16
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the rounding mode used. The implication holds for the following three rounding modes:

```
* Round Nearest Ties To Away
* Round Nearest Ties To Even
* Round Toward Positive
```

But it does *not* hold for the following two rounding modes:

```
* Round Toward Negative
* Round Toward Zero
```

As a counter-example with `Round Toward Zero`, take:

```
a = 0x1.008084p-66
b = 0x1.008082p-66
```

where `a` and `b` are single-precision floats. Then division produces precisely `1.0`; and thus violates the strict greater-than requirement. The same values also provide a counter-example for `Round Toward Negative`.